# Cisco LACP MEC on 7200 chassis

Tags: cisco, lacp

I'm currently trying to make some kind of setup like this:

2 Routers 7206VXR / NPE-G1 connected both at Gigabit speed to 2 devices (named D2).

There is already a redundancy mechanism on both D2 to faill over the slave in case the master broke down.

I don't know yet which feature should I use on both Cisco 7206 routers in order to make also the faill-over (depending on the GE port status).

I saw that LACP MultiChassis EtherChannel (MEC) could help me but I really don't figure how to make that setup. I found Cisco guides but nowhere I can see how the setup inter-router does work (I guess they need to speak together to see the status of each other + port priority)...

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

7200 can't do MEC, mostly used in Cisco VSS (a pair of 6500 chassis as one entity).

Depending on what you want to achieve the typical fail-over of a 7200 is to use HSRP where they IP address of the router address can fail-over between the two boxes.

Comment: HSRP or OSPF/EIGRP/iBGP if you have devices supporting it